# my thread ignore flag interrupt

Tags: java, android, multithreading

hi mate i have a simple thread that i want to terminate when flag interrupt is on.
this is the code at the begin of run method

```
conn = false;
for (int i=0; (isInterrupted() == false) && (i < TRY_CONNECT) && !conn; i++) {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG,"TRY"+i);
        sock.connect();
        conn = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            Log.d(TAG,"CATCH int");
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(isInterruped() == true)
    Log.d(TAG,"INT");
```

out the  thread i call on him interrupt method, and it dont terminate the loop.. he dont see the interrupt that i call... how is possible ?
For debug: out where i call interrupt i insert two print with log cat ... thread_reader.interrupt(); boolean b=thread_reader.isInterrupted(); Log.d(TAG,""+b); and on log cat the system print "false" how is possible ? i ve just call interrupt

Comment: How are we suppose to help you if we don't even know what programming language this is?

Comment: Looks a lot like Java to me, so I tagged it as such.

Comment: sorry for my english i explain better the concept... if i put break inside cath interrupt exception i solve the problem only if when i interrupt the thread , it is sleeping... but if itsnt sleeping ,my interrupt dont generate interrupt exception... the thread should see the flag in the header of loop... but nothing why ? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you catch `InterruptedException`, simply break the loop. Do not rely on `isInterrupted()` check in the loop header, as the interrupted flag is cleared when the `InterruptedException` is thrown.

Comment: the flag is cleared on InterruptedException?

Comment: yes if use break now its ok... but if when i call interrupt the thread is'nt sleep the loop dont see the interrupt why ?

Comment: (isInterrupted()==false) dont see my interrupt

Comment: sorry for my english i explain better the concept... if i put break inside cath interrupt exception i solve the problem only if when i interrupt the thread , it is sleeping... but if itsnt sleeping ,my interrupt dont generate interrupt exception... the thread should see the flag in the header of loop... but nothing why ?

Comment: when it is not sleeping, it checks isInterrupted(), which just returns interrupted status, and never throws exception.

Comment: ok but if is has the flag isInterrupted() should return true and loop should break but my loop continue , why ?

Comment: you call isInterrupted() just after sleep() finished without throwing InterruptedException, so the flag is not set. I am not sure if sock.connect() can throw InterruptedException because you did not tell what type of sock is.

Comment: BluetoothSocket of android , the flag must be set if not throw InterruptedException and i call interrupt..

Comment: If connection succeed, you set conn = true, but do not break the loop, why?

Comment: ok but itsnt the problem, i test with a device where fail every try because the device is off

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you catch `InterruptedException` this *clears* the interrupt flag on the thread.  You need to do something like following pattern as a matter of course every time you do the catch:

```
try {
     sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
     Log.d(TAG,"CATCH int");
     // _always_ re-interrupt the thread since the interrupt flag is cleared
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     // you probably want to break
     break;
}
```

As @Alexei mentioned, you could put a `break` or `return` in the catch block to exit the thread immediately.  But either way, you should always re-interrupt the `Thread` so that other parts of your program can detect that an interrupt condition was set on the `Thread`.

See this question/answer for more information:

> [Why would you catch InterruptedException to call Thread.currentThread.interrupt()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895881/why-would-you-catch-interruptedexception-to-call-thread-currentthread-interrupt)

Comment: sorry for my english i explain better the concept... if i put break inside cath interrupt exception i solve the problem only if when i interrupt the thread , it is sleeping... but if itsnt sleeping ,my interrupt dont generate interrupt exception... the thread should see the flag in the header of loop... but nothing why ?

Comment: And you know this because if you put in a `break` and interrupt the thread, it doesn't always stop the loop @dario?  Any chance that you are calling other code which has a `sleep(...)` or other statement that is catching `InterruptedException` and _not_ re-interrupting the thread?

Comment: if the thread is sleeping  and i interrupt: system throw interupt exception and i catch it and break the loop and its all OK... but if when  i interrupt the thread isn't sleeping there arent exception but the thread should have interrupt flag set to true but when i test it in the header of loop it is false... this is the problem ! please help me :)

Comment: out where i call interrupt i insert two print  with log cat ...             thread_reader.interrupt();
         boolean b=thread_reader.isInterrupted();
          Log.d(TAG,""+b);   and on log cat the system print "false" how is possible ? i ve just call interrupt

Comment: It is possible if the thread caught `InterruptedException` and did not re-interrupt itself.  Did you do a `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the _catch_ block of the `InterruptedException`?

Comment: i debug and i try to press interrupt() when thread is'nt sleeeping and when the thread check it find the flag=false..

Comment: if it isn't sleeping then what does it do? sock.connect()? Then it start sleeping after it and the flag triggers immediately when sleep is called, and then exception is thrown and flag is cleared. After that, isInterrupted() is invoked and sees the flag=false. So what do you expect instead?

Comment: suppose that when i call interrupt() the thread is executing connect(), the thread continue his execution and when return to the header of loop he should find the flag of interrupt on but the loop continue so he found the flag off... its a bug

Comment: sleep clear the interruption flag ?

Comment: i solve it ! sleep clear flag ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401947/methods-that-clear-the-thread-interrupt-flag thanks for hep

Comment: No.  That question is misleading @dario.  I've edited it.  `Thread.sleep()` clears the interrupt flag by immediately throwing `InterruptedException` either if the thread is interrupted while it is sleeping or if it has already been interrupted when sleep is called.

Comment: there arent solution... i think it is a bug of java

Comment: Sigh.  You think wrong @Dario.  There is no bug.  It is working as designed/documented.