# Why should we use wait() method inside the try block ? Can we use wait() method outside the try block?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here I am using wait() method in try block  for the inter communication between threads. I used wait method outside the try block but it was showing exception.

```
try
{
    System.out.println(" why we should use wait() method in try block  ");
    wait();
}
    catch()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the [JavaDocs for `Object#wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--), you will see it throws two exceptions, `IllegalMonitorStateException`, which is a `RuntimeException` and `InterruptedException` which is a caught exception, which you MUST handle, so, no, you must call `wait` in a `try-catch` OR re throw the exception

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says, you must either catch the InterruptedException, or your method needs to declare that it throws it

Answer (score 3):

> Q: Why should we use wait() method inside the try block?

You use a `wait()` inside a `synchronized` block or `synchronized` method.

```
synchronized (this) {
    while (!this.isTeapot) {
        this.wait();
    }
    System.out.println("I am a teapot");
}
```

And in another method ...

```
synchronized (this) {
    this.isTeapot = true;
    this.notify();
}
```

Why?

- Because the spec says so.
- Because you will get an `IllegalMonitorStateException` if you don't.

But why?

- Because it is not possible to implement wait / notify condition variables safely without this restriction.  The requirement is essential for thread safety; i.e. to avoid race conditions and memory anomalies.

The `try` block is not mandatory.  Use a `try` block if you need to deal with an exception *at that level*.  If not, allow it to propagate.  This includes `InterruptedException` ... though since it is a checked exception, you would need to declare it in the method's `throws` clause if you didn't catch it locally.  But this is just normal Java exception handling.  Nothing special.

For example:

```
try {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (!this.isTeapot) {
            this.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("I am a teapot");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

(For an explanation of the above example, see [Why would you catch InterruptedException to call Thread.currentThread.interrupt()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895881/why-would-you-catch-interruptedexception-to-call-thread-currentthread-interrupt).)

> Q: Can we use wait() method outside the try block?

You cannot call `wait()` outside of a `synchronized` block or `synchronized` method.  (See above.)

The `try` block is not mandatory.  (See above.)

Comment: up!!!hi, you may need write a simple example. e.g: a synchronized method  throws exceptions that `wait` will be threw.